# How to truncate title in a custom title view in nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I'm setting an image and text as title view in Nav bar. The text doesn't truncate if it's too long, how to truncate it? I've custom back button and a right icon in nav bar too.

```
let navView = UIView()

let label = UILabel()
label.text = self.name
label.sizeToFit()
label.center = navView.center
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
label.textColor = .white
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

navView.addSubview(label)
navView.addSubview(avatarImage)

self.navigationItem.titleView = navView

navView.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried different methods but none worked. As a workaround I achieved this by restricting number of characters in title text and appending ... at the end. It's not a perfect solution but haven't got anything better till now.